# How do I set svg path style in js?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I have path, that's how it looks in svg

```
<path
   style="fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1"
   d="m 117.14283,292.36218 c 6.4302,40.00204 17.7957,72.08138 42.8572,97.14285 41.9864,41.98645 170.1489,-58.42248 108.5714,-120 -34.4011,-34.4011 -81.0249,123.66456 -65.7143,154.28572 20.1806,40.36118 166.194,14.76546 134.2857,-17.14286 -49.3132,-49.31326 -75.8868,85.36926 -60,117.14286 30.4479,60.89583 115.0776,-13.49389 97.1429,-31.42857 -3.4884,-3.48837 -113.508,91.67283 -22.8572,157.14285"
   id="path3024"
   inkscape:connector-curvature="0" />
```

And I select it in js code like this

```
var path = svg.select("#" + options["pathid"]);
```

so how do I change stroke-opacity value?

This way doesn't work =(

```
var path = svg.select("#" + options["pathid"])
      .style('stroke', '#ff0000');
```

=======================================================

`path.style("stroke-opacity", 0);` works and

```
alert(path.style("stroke-opacity")); // returns 0,
```

but nothing changed when I start svg in browser, and tag didn't change at all in code. Any ideas?

Comment: .style('stroke-opacity', 0.5) for example does not work? You can also check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15790948/modifying-svg-path-opacity-and-its-marker).

Comment: this way doesn't work too

Comment: If you create a fiddle it would be helpful to all.

Answer (score 1):

Using JavaScript , you can easily change attributes.

```
path.setAttribute('stroke','red');
path.setAttribute('stroke-width','2');
```

Answer (score 0):

If svg has already been selected by d3, then to access that path you could use:

```
var path = svg.select("#path3024")
```

Then the style can be changed as you have shown.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
.attr('stroke', '#ff0000');
```